# Regular expression will not find all required items

Tags: java, regex

Hi I am making a price checker that returns the cheapest item name and price from a supermarket website.
Most prices in the code are in the format ...price:3.14... but some prices are just simply ...price:2...

This is the website with an example search already entered, view the source code if you wish
http://www.tesco.ie/groceries/product/search/default.aspx?searchBox=ham

My regular expression that I have usually picks up 18/20 items from the source code but when it hits a price of just 1 digit the arraylist becomes out of sync.

My question is how do I get the regular expression to pick up both types and add them to the arraylist to keep it in sync.

Here is the regex that gets the price

String priceFinder = "price:(\d{1,3})(.\d{1,2})";

Here is the more code if it helps

```
  public static Product addProducts(String item)  throws Exception {

            //@SuppressWarnings("resource")

            productList.clear();
            item = checkCommonItems(item);
            item = item.replaceAll("\\s+", "%20");

            URL oracle = new URL("http://www.tesco.ie/groceries/product/search/default.aspx?searchBox="+item);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

            String inputLine;
            String name, price;
            int productArrayNumber = 0;

            String nameFinder = "name:\"([\\w{1,15} ]*)";
            String priceFinder = "price:(\\d{1,3})(.\\d{1,2})";
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                    Pattern namePattern = Pattern.compile(nameFinder);              
                    Matcher nameMatcher = namePattern.matcher(inputLine);
                    Pattern pricePattern = Pattern.compile(priceFinder);
                    Matcher priceMatcher = pricePattern.matcher(inputLine);

                    while(nameMatcher.find()){
                            exists = false;
                            name = nameMatcher.group(1);
                            for(int i = 0; i < productList.size();i++)
                            {
                                    Product productExists = productList.get(i);
                                    if(productExists.getProductName().equals(name))
                                    {
                                            exists = true;
                                    }                              
                            }
                            if(exists== false)
                            {

                                    Product productNew =new Product(name,null);
                                    productList.add(productNew);
                            }

                    }
                    while(priceMatcher.find() && productArrayNumber<productList.size()){
                            price = priceMatcher.group(1);
                            price = price + priceMatcher.group(2);
                            Product productEdit = (Product) productList.get(productArrayNumber);
                            productEdit.setProductPrice(price);    
                            productList.set(productArrayNumber, productEdit);              
                            productArrayNumber++;
                    }
            }
            Product cheapest = null;
            if(productList.size() != 0)
            {

                    cheapest = productList.get(0);
                    for (int a = 0; a < productList.size()-1; a++)
                    {
                        System.out.println(productList.get(a));
                            Double chpPrice = Double.parseDouble(cheapest.getProductPrice());
                            Double cmpPrice = 500.0;
                            if(productList.get(a).getProductPrice() != null)
                            {
                                    cmpPrice = Double.parseDouble(productList.get(a).getProductPrice());
                                    if(chpPrice > cmpPrice)
                                    {
                                            cheapest = productList.get(a);
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                    in.close();
            }

            return cheapest;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your problem is only in regex, since you claim that it works normally for prices containing `.\\d{1,2}` part. Your problem is probably that you are not escaping `.` since it is special character in regex. Also you are not checking if there is `.\\d{1,2}` before you add it to `price`.

Try maybe `price:(\\d{1,3}(\\.\\d{1,2})?)` and use `price = priceMatcher.group(1);`

Comment: Accepted, sorry I am new to posting questions here.